# Why am I getting "Class not found" errors when migrating or seeding my Lumen application?

Tags: laravel, lumen

I have a Laravel Lumen application and I am trying to use migrations and database seeds, but I keep getting errors similar to this:

```
[ReflectionException]

Class DatabaseSeeder does not exist
```

`class 'CreateTableX' does not exist`

How do I fix this?

Comment: I think you should run composer dump-autoload after create new seed class or you can refer this tutorial http://wsnippets.com/create-rest-api-using-lumen-micro-framework-by-laravel/

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the database folder to the autoload of your `composer.json` file.

NOTE: As of Lumen 5.0.2 the folders are already added to `composer.json`.

**Step 1**

Add this section to the "autoload" object (under your psr-4 object) in composer.json:

```
    "classmap": [
        "database/"
    ]
```

**Step 2**

Once added, run `composer dump-autoload` so that composer can load the classes from the newly added folder.

---

Source: https://github.com/laravel/lumen/commit/d28be75b5f5c6e45641d6babfd8c4e59a09504e5